# how to find farthest 3 consecutive elements from an array

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have an array of possible positions and another array of filled positions which is a subarray of the `possiblePositionsArray`. `possiblePositionsArray` is fixed in number and already determined. I would like to find the farthest 3 consecutive points to the right and the left of a selected array element's x position in `filledPositions`. Let me explain further with this example.
Say

```
possiblePositionsArray = [p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15]
filledPositions = [p1, p2, p4, p7, p8, p9, p10, p12, p13, p14, p15]
```

Both are arrays of `CGPoint`s and all have the same y positions and are arranged in ascending order.
If I select `p11.x` the following will be the 3 consecutive points to the right and the left.

```
[p7, p8, p9] and [p8, p9, p10] To the Left of p11
[p12, p13, p14] and [p13, p14, p15] to the right of p11
```

But the farthest to the left and right would be:

```
farthest to left of p11 is [p7, p8, p9]
farthest to right of p11 is [p13, p14, p15]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Start at the end of the array and count backwards. The first consecutive grouping you find is the farthest along in the array.

Comment: You write that `y` is the same for all items. Is that correct?  If so then perhaps only work with x values in your post

Comment: Are the `x` values equally spaced apart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First start from the beginning of `filledPositions`. Find the first item from `filledPositions` in `possiblePositionsArray`. Check if the next two items from both arrays match each other. The first consecutive group is the furthest to the left of your selected element. This works even if the `x` values in `possiblePositionsArray` elements are not equally spaced apart.

After that you do this in reversed order to find the furthest to the right.

The code for that would be something like this:

```
let selectedElement = yourSelectedElement

//left consecutive group   
var consLeft = [CGPoint]()
//right consecutive group
var consRight = [CGPoint]()

if filledPositions.count >= 3 {
    for i in 0..<filledPositions.count-2 {
        // find the index of the element from filledPositions in possiblePositionsArray
        let indexInPossiblePostionArray = possiblePositionsArray.indexOf(filledPositions[i])!

        if indexInPossiblePostionArray < possiblePositionsArray.count-2 && // safety check
            filledPositions[i+2].x < selectedElement.x &&  // Only check left of selected element
            //check equality of second items
            filledPositions[i+1].x == possiblePositionsArray[indexInPossiblePostionArray+1].x &&
            //check equality of third items
            filledPositions[i+2].x == possiblePositionsArray[indexInPossiblePostionArray+2].x {
            //3 consecutive elements to left selected element was found
            for j in i...i+2 {
                //add to left consecutive group
                consLeft.append(filledPositions[j])
            }
            //break out of the for loop
            break
        }
    }

    //The same thing in reversed order
    for i in (2..<filledPositions.count).reverse() {
        let indexInPossiblePostionArray = possiblePositionsArray.indexOf(filledPositions[i])!

        if indexInPossiblePostionArray-2 >= 0 &&
            filledPositions[i-2].x > selectedElement.x &&
            filledPositions[i-1].x == possiblePositionsArray[indexInPossiblePostionArray-1].x &&
            filledPositions[i-2].x == possiblePositionsArray[indexInPossiblePostionArray-2].x {
            for j in i-2...i {
                consRight.append(filledPositions[j])
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
```